# Integral Over the N-Sphere in the framework of chains:

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms, geometric-topology

Integration over manifolds is commonly defined with object called chains. What about if I want to integrate the exterior derivative of a $k-form$ over the n-sphere and use Stokes theorem:

\begin{eqnarray}
    \int_{\sigma} d\omega 
    &=&
    \int_{\partial \sigma} \omega 
\end{eqnarray}

I found in several books that this integral is zero, they argue it's because the sphere is compact so its boundary is zero.

My question is how can I relate this with chains??, I menan, how is the chain for a n-sphere and why its boundary is zero...